# SVG Logo animation

Tags: animation, svg, scroll

So I have a client logo and I want to animate it on scroll. Let's say that the logo is DANIEL. As the user scrolls down the page i want the spacing between the letters to expand so it would end up being D  A  N   I   E   L.
I have seen how to do this with regular text but this will be as I said an SVG logo. I have been searching around buy didn't find anything. Also needs to be mobile friendly.  Any tips out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually very simple.  You just need to watch for scroll events, then update the `<text>` element based on how far down the page you have scrolled.

I've achieved the letter spacing using the `letter-spacing` presentation attribute.

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  document.getElementById("mytext").setAttribute("letter-spacing", (window.scrollY / window.outerHeight) + "em");
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
}

svg {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 600 100">
  <text id="mytext" x="300" y="70" font-size="50" text-anchor="middle">DANIEL</text>
</svg>
```

**Update**

For other non-text elements, like `<path>` etc, you will need to take a slightly different approah.  You'll need to physically move them with a `transform`.

Here is a quick demo. You'll need to tweak it to get the objects to move where you want them.

```js
var EXPAND_AMOUNT = 40;

window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  var scrollPercent = window.scrollY / window.outerHeight;
  document.getElementById("obj1").setAttribute("transform", "translate("+(scrollPercent * 3 * -EXPAND_AMOUNT)+",0)");
  document.getElementById("obj2").setAttribute("transform", "translate("+(scrollPercent * 2 * -EXPAND_AMOUNT)+",0)");
  document.getElementById("obj3").setAttribute("transform", "translate("+(scrollPercent * -EXPAND_AMOUNT)+",0)");
  document.getElementById("obj4").setAttribute("transform", "translate("+(scrollPercent * EXPAND_AMOUNT)+",0)");
  document.getElementById("obj5").setAttribute("transform", "translate("+(scrollPercent * 2 * EXPAND_AMOUNT)+",0)");
  document.getElementById("obj6").setAttribute("transform", "translate("+(scrollPercent * 3 * EXPAND_AMOUNT)+",0)");
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
}

svg {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 600 100">
  <rect id="obj1" x="165" y="25" width="40" height="50"/>
  <rect id="obj2" x="210" y="25" width="40" height="50"/>
  <rect id="obj3" x="255" y="25" width="40" height="50"/>
  <rect id="obj4" x="300" y="25" width="40" height="50"/>
  <rect id="obj5" x="345" y="25" width="40" height="50"/>
  <rect id="obj6" x="390" y="25" width="40" height="50"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Hi Paul. Thanks for your response - really appreciate it. That is just what i am after - but how would that work if Daniel is not a font but an SVG (client logo)?

Comment: Hej Paul - So i got this to work - but it was a bit of a hack. I ended up making a icon font of the logo. It works well on desktop but not on mobile - any ideas?

Comment: Not from that description :). What exactly does "not work well" mean?

Comment: One problem is that because the font icons are put in as html elements (?) I can’t make them white - which is how they should be - plus it doesn’t work on mobile. Any thoughts on the colour?

Comment: If you add `fill: white` to your `<text>` element, it doesn't make the text white?

Comment: The text animates for me in Android Chrome.

Comment: Hi Paul. Thanks again. Now I have white text. One step closer! I can't tell you how many things i tried last week to get that working. I still don't have an expanding logo though on my iPhone (I've tried it both on ios safari and chrome). Any final thoughts?

Comment: I don't have an iPhone, so I can't try it to see. I would suggest asking a new question specifically about that issue, and tag it appropriately.  Eg. with `ios` and/or `iphone`.

Comment: Will do. Thanks again for all your help.